# How to remove value on the second end of y axis

Tags: c#, charts

[image]

How to remove these values which can be round i want to make graph with respect of the value which are on the first end of chart how can i remove the values which i mark in the pics kindly help .I make my project with help of stackoverflow platform professional guidance now its end of my project so plz help me

how to remove the values which shows on the second end of the chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I point out problem i make all Y-Axis Secondary Axis now i change it to Primary Axis so problem resolved

AxisType.Secondary(Create Problem)

AxisType.Primary (Solution)